# Django abstract model inheritance - make all fields nullable

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have an `AbstractModel`, `Model` and `DraftModel`.

I need `DraftModel` to inherit from `AbstractModel`, but all `inherited` fields should be `null=True`. I can't change `Model` fields to `null=True` since there is too much logic built on that.

I prefer not overriding manually all fields.

I tried:

```
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    for field in self._meta.fields:
        field.null = True
```

Which does not work, do you have any idea?

**EDIT**

I figured out one solution (check my answer) but you are open to add yours.

Answer (score 2):

Changing fields inside `__init__` doesn't work because there is no call.

Adding this snippet under the `DrafModel` works:

```
for field in DraftModel._meta.fields:
    field.null = True
```

Of course, you should exclude fields like `PrimaryKey` or `BooleanField`

**EDIT**

For my purposes, this works:

```
for field in DraftModel._meta.fields:
     if not field.primary_key and not isinstance(field, models.BooleanField):
          field.null = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `__call__` method:

```
class DraftModel(SomeAbstractModel):

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for f in self.__class__._meta.fields:
            if f.name not in ['id'] and not isinstance(f, models.BooleanField):  # copy pasted from your answer
                f.null = True
        super(DraftModel, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```